# T-SQL Incorrect syntax near '@countTable'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this code:

```
declare @countTable int;  
set @countTable = 1;

create table #TempDadosExport 
(
     defprodutoid int, 
     nome varchar(250), 
     Categoria varchar(250),
     tipoorigem varchar(250),
     Campanha varchar(250), 
     PopUpId int
);

insert into #TempDadosExport(defprodutoid, nome, Categoria, tipoorigem, Campanha, @countTable)
```

But when I try to use `@countTable` to insert, I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@countTable'.

Comment: Your `INSERT` syntax is wrong.  You need `INSERT INTO Table ([cols...]) VALUES ([vals...])`

Comment: [T-SQL `INSERT` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You can also use a dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a column name as a variable in an `insert` statement unless you use dynamic SQL.

Your `insert` is specifying a list of columns to insert into, but no values.

I *suspect* what you mean to write is

```
insert into #TempDadosExport(defprodutoid, nome, Categoria,tipoorigem,Campanha,popupid) select defprodutoid, nome, Categoria,tipoorigem,Campanha, @countTable from OTHERTABLE
```